# PLSQL triggers and normal triggers

Tags: plsql, triggers

Could anyone tell me difference between PLSQL trigger and trigger. In oracle docs I am finding two chapters of triggers. I am unable to get clear picture between those two

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the reference on Oracle Triggers (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020) you'll see this:

> A trigger is a named PL/SQL unit that is stored in the database and
>   executed (fired) in response to a specified event that occurs in the
>   database.

So triggers are written in PL/SQL, which is why you find the syntax in the PL/SQL reference (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020).

Bottom line, there is only one object being discussed: a trigger.  A trigger is an object in the database written in PL/SQL.  It is described generally in the Oracle documentation and again in the PL/SQL language reference.